# How can I determine, for each year between 2017 and 2020, which day of the week had the maximum number of events held on a month-wise basis?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table event_ with two columns (event_id and date of the event)

```
+----------+------------+
| event_id | event_date |
+----------+------------+
| 21       | 2017-01-29 |
| 27       | 2018-01-16 |
| 45       | 2017-01-27 |
| 49       | 2018-01-29 |
| 59       | 2017-01-24 |
| 71       | 2017-01-30 |
| 73       | 2017-01-14 |
| 79       | 2017-01-16 |
| 101      | 2019-01-03 |
| 102      | 2020-01-12 |
| 119      | 2017-01-30 |
| 122      | 2019-01-18 |
| 144      | 2020-01-24 |
| 159      | 2018-01-16 |
| 164      | 2017-01-03 |
| 171      | 2018-01-17 |
| 190      | 2018-01-02 |
| 193      | 2018-01-08 |
| 200      | 2019-01-07 |
| 230      | 2017-01-23 |
| 239      | 2017-01-06 |
| 256      | 2020-01-01 |
| 277      | 2017-01-13 |
| 291      | 2018-01-17 |
| 328      | 2017-01-10 |
| 332      | 2018-01-22 |
| 341      | 2018-01-12 |
| 348      | 2019-01-17 |
| 388      | 2017-01-05 |
+----------+------------+
```

DDL & DML

```
create table event_ (event_id int , event_date date );

insert into event_ (event_id,event_date) values(21,"2017-01-29"),(27,"2018-01-16"),(45,"2017-01-27"),(49,"2018-01-29"),(59,"2017-01-24"),(71,"2017-01-30"),(73,"2017-01-14"),(79,"2017-01-16"),(101,"2019-01-03"),(102,"2020-01-12"),(119,"2017-01-30"),(122,"2019-01-18"),(144,"2020-01-24"),(159,"2018-01-16"),(164,"2017-01-03"),(171,"2018-01-17"),(190,"2018-01-02"),(193,"2018-01-08"),(200,"2019-01-07"),(230,"2017-01-23"),(239,"2017-01-06"),(256,"2020-01-01"),(277,"2017-01-13"),(291,"2018-01-17"),(328,"2017-01-10"),(332,"2018-01-22"),(341,"2018-01-12"),(348,"2019-01-17"),(388,"2017-01-05");
```

I would like to obtain a month-wise analysis for each year between 2017 and 2020. Specifically, for each month in those years, I want to determine the day of the week with the maximum number of events. If there are multiple weekdays with the same maximum number of events for a particular month in a given year, I would like to identify all the weekday names.

Below I mentioned expected output:

```
month     2017          2018            2019            2020
  1       Monday   Monday,Tuesday  Thursday    Friday,Sunday,Wednesday
```

All the help would be appreciated.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Hey thanks for replying this my first time posting , so i might have messed up a bit but i have edited the ques as of now . hope it helps

Comment: hey thanks for replaying , i did whatever possible edit , hope it helps and date format is as you mentioned .

Comment: "I tried using windows function ..."  So where's this query???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to do this in two steps.

1. GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, WEEKDAY, and add RANK()
2. Select the days ranked #1 per month and pivot per year

Step 1

```
SELECT
    YEAR(`event_date`) AS `year`,
    MONTH(`event_date`) AS `month`,
    WEEKDAY(`event_date`) AS `day_num`,
    DAYNAME(`event_date`) AS `day_name`,
    COUNT(*) AS `count`,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(`event_date`), MONTH(`event_date`) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS `rank`
FROM `event_`
GROUP BY `year`, `month`, `day_num`, `day_name`
ORDER BY `year`, `month`, `rank`;
```

Output:

| year | month | day_num | day_name | count | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 1 | 0 | Monday | 4 | 1 |
| 2017 | 1 | 4 | Friday | 3 | 2 |
| 2017 | 1 | 1 | Tuesday | 3 | 2 |
| 2017 | 1 | 6 | Sunday | 1 | 4 |
| 2017 | 1 | 5 | Saturday | 1 | 4 |
| 2017 | 1 | 3 | Thursday | 1 | 4 |
| 2018 | 1 | 1 | Tuesday | 3 | 1 |
| 2018 | 1 | 0 | Monday | 3 | 1 |
| 2018 | 1 | 2 | Wednesday | 2 | 3 |
| 2018 | 1 | 4 | Friday | 1 | 4 |
| 2019 | 1 | 3 | Thursday | 2 | 1 |
| 2019 | 1 | 4 | Friday | 1 | 2 |
| 2019 | 1 | 0 | Monday | 1 | 2 |
| 2020 | 1 | 6 | Sunday | 1 | 1 |
| 2020 | 1 | 4 | Friday | 1 | 1 |
| 2020 | 1 | 2 | Wednesday | 1 | 1 |

Step 2

```sql
WITH `ranked` (`year`, `month`, `day_num`, `day_name`, `rank`) AS (
    SELECT
        YEAR(`event_date`),
        MONTH(`event_date`),
        WEEKDAY(`event_date`),
        DAYNAME(`event_date`),
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(`event_date`), MONTH(`event_date`) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
    FROM `event_`
    GROUP BY `year`, `month`, `day_num`, `day_name`
)
SELECT `month`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`year` = 2017, `day_name`, NULL) ORDER BY `day_num`) AS `2017`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`year` = 2018, `day_name`, NULL) ORDER BY `day_num`) AS `2018`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`year` = 2019, `day_name`, NULL) ORDER BY `day_num`) AS `2019`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`year` = 2020, `day_name`, NULL) ORDER BY `day_num`) AS `2020`
FROM `ranked`
WHERE `rank` = 1
GROUP BY `month`;
```

Output:

| month | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Monday | Monday,Tuesday | Thursday | Wednesday,Friday,Sunday |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yivJPajD).

Comment: A huge thank you ...  and also thank you for editing in such a way that others can understand .

Comment: You're welcome! Please remember in future, to make sure you include all the relevant information and to format your question appropriately. The more effort you put in, the more likely it is that you will get help quickly.